# if-else error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

Here is my shell script and the error I get when running it:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
execute=$2
a=$3
operation=$4
name=$5

if [ "$operation" == "run" ]; then
    cd $path
   ./$execute $a 
fi
elif [ "$operation" == "copy" ]; then
    mkdir -p $path
    cp $execute $path/$name 
fi
elif [ "$operation" == "delete" ]; then
     rm $path
     cd copy
     rm $name
     cd ..
     rmdir copy
fi
```

> ```
> ./commandsScript.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
> ./commandsScript.sh: line 14: `elif [ "$operation" == "copy" ]; then'
> ```

I've spent a long time trying all sort if-else statements variances but have not found the error solution. May someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a `case` expression instead of a set of chained `if` statements:

```
case "$operation" in
run)
    cd "$path"
    ./"$execute" "$a"
    ;; 
copy)
    mkdir -p "$path"
    cp "$execute" "$path/$name"
    ;;
delete)
    rm "$path"
    cd copy
    rm "$name"
    cd ..
    rmdir copy
    ;;
esac
```

I've also taken the liberty to quote all of your parameter expansions, which is what you should get into the habit of doing to make your script robust against arguments/variables with embedded whitespace.

Also, I would advise investing in proper error handling.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the first and second `fi`. It should look like

```
if ...
...
elif ...
...
elif ...
...
fi
```

See [Bash - Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) for more details.